# WordPress-CSS: Set equal height on video players

Tags: css, wordpress, video-player

I am trying to add 4 video players in the same line in Wordpress using WP Bakery builder as shown below.

Video players screenshot:

[image: Video players screenshot]

As you can see only the first video player is not equal height as the other 3.
What should i change in the CSS to fix this?

Comment: try something like this ```height:50%!important;```

Comment: Please provide us with your code snippet(s) so that we could debug it for you!!!